# Scroll position in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-events

In Javascript, I wanted to understand a few things:

1. Can we both get/set scroll pos for a window?
2. What is the diff between window scroll pos and for normal element on page?
3. Can we set scroll pos for any HTML elements or is it only for those with overflow properties?
4. Is there any difference in these property calc for iPad?
5. For `scrollWidth`, does it get affected by vertical scrollbars..If yes, is it the same in all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers.

1. `$(window).scrollTop()`, `$(window).scrollTop(100)`;
2. `window` scroll position is the main page's scroll postion(left/top) where as for normal element the scroll position applies when we set overflow:auto to it and then we can get/set the scroll position of it.
3. We can get the scroll position of any element using `$("selector").scrollTop()/scrollLeft()` but yes if the overflow is not auto then I think it will always return 0.
4. For iPad the `scrollTop()/scrollLeft()` do not work, you have to use `window.pageYOffset/window.pageXOffset`

JavaScript equivalents, not tested though across browsers

`$(window).scrollTop()` - `document.documentElement.scrollTop/scrollLeft`
`$("selector").scrollLeft()` - `document.getElementById("elementId").offsetTop/offsetLeft`

Comment: What is syntax difference for normal html elememt scroll pos?

Comment: Also on iPad, i can see scrollTop ..testing on http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/elementdimensions.html

Comment: The syntax is same for normal html elements. scrollTop is there on iPad but it does not give you correct value. I have used it my iPad web page.

Comment: Ok..not sure why i feel to be getting correctly on the dem page...anyways i have also added 5th question...

Comment: Can u just highlight a mapping of normal JS vs jQuery methods for these?

Comment: Check my edited answer and if you are satisfied please mark this as an answer, thanks.